# How to create dynamic substring with awk

Tags: bash, awk

Let say i have file like below.

```
ABC_DEF_G-1_P-249_8.CSV
```

I want to cut to be like this below.

```
ABC_DEF_G-1_P-249_
```

I use this awk command to do that like below.

```
ls -lrt |  grep -i .CSV | tail -1 | awk -F ' ' '{print $8}' | cut -c 1-18
```

**Question is**, if the number 1, is growing, how to make the substring is dynamic

example like below...

```
ABC_DEF_G-1_P-249_
....
ABC_DEF_G-10_P-249_
ABC_DEF_G-11_P-249_
...
ABC_DEF_G-1000_P-249_
```

Comment: Do I understand this right: you want to rename all files with `.CSV` extension by removing everything after the last `_` from the name?

Comment: Or do you just want to display the shortened names, as your command does?

Comment: [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: hi, that one i get into a variable, of course i want to generate a CSV files, i just wants that number to dynamic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with just ls and grep

```
 ls -1rt | grep -oP ".*(?=_\d{1,}\.CSV)"
```

If you are concerned about the output of ls -1, as mentioned in the comments you can use find as well

```
find -type f -printf "%f\n" | grep -oP ".*(?=_\d{1,}\.CSV)"
```

Outputs:

```
 ABC_DEF_G-1_P-249
 ABC_DEF_G-1000_P-249_
```

This assumes you want everything except the _number.CSV, if it needs to be case insensitive then you can the `-i` flag to the grep. The `\d{1,}` allows for the number between _ and .CSV to grow from one to many digits. Also doing it this way you don't have to worry about if the number 1 in your example increases:

> ABC_DEF_G-**1**_P-249

Comment: hi john it works, but if i take that as a variable, it would not read because it have \n, any idea ?

Comment: The final trailing newline will be discarded when you assign the output of a command to a variable in the shell.

Comment: so how to do with \n if i try your command to use as a variable ?, example is like this \nABC_DEF_G-1248_P-249_26.CSV' for reading: File name too long, it is take as a one line if i use as a variable

Comment: @John K : so how to do with \n if i try your command to use as a variable ?, example is like this \nABC_DEF_G-1248_P-249_26.CSV' for reading: File name too long, it is take as a one line if i use as a variable

Comment: @AmirRachman I am confused as to what you are asking regarding `\n`. Also why is the file name considered "too long"? Too long for what ? If you  assign the output of this command to a variable you will get an line of file names. If you echo without double quotes you will get a single line, otherwise you will get a \n delimited output. Now if you are assigning the output to a variable with the intention of looping through it as an array, then all you should have to do is something like this: `array=($output)` or `read -a arr <<< $output`

Comment: it's close @JohnK thanks for your help...

Answer (score 3):

To display the file names of all `.CSV` without everything after the last underscore, you can do this:

```
for fname in *.CSV; do echo "${fname%_*}_"; done
```

This removes the last underscore and evertyhing that follows it (`${fname%_*}`), and then appends an underscore again. You can assign that, for example, to another variable.

For an example file list of

```
ABC_DEF_G-1_P-249_9.CSV
ABC_DEF_G-10_P-249_8.CSV
ABC_DEF_G-1000_P-249_4.CSV
ABC_DEF_G-11_P-249_7.CSV
ABC_DEF_G-11_P-249_7.txt
```

this results in

```
$ for fname in *.CSV; do echo "${fname%_*}_"; done
ABC_DEF_G-1_P-249_
ABC_DEF_G-10_P-249_
ABC_DEF_G-1000_P-249_
ABC_DEF_G-11_P-249_
```

Comment: for that command how to given as a variable in unix shell

Comment: @AmirRachman Not sure I understand: what is given as a variable?

Comment: @AmirRachman I still don't understand, I'm afraid.

Comment: no worry i found my way, best on above command... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not be parsing `ls`.  Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
base=$(printf "%s\n" * | grep -i .CSV | tail -1 | awk -F ' ' '{print $8}' | cut -c 1-18)
```

However, that's a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) you want to get rid of right there -- Awk does everything `grep` does, and everything `tail` does, too, and actually, everything `cut` does as well.  The `grep` can also be avoided by using a better wildcard, though:

```
base=$(printf "%s\n" *.[Cc][Ss][Vv] | awk 'END { print substr($8, 1, 18) }')
```

In the shell itself, you can do much the same thing with no external processes at all.  Proposing a suitable workaround would perhaps require a better understanding of what you are trying to accomplish, though.